# pyautogui.pixel() function does not get the correct pixel values on my iMac

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014), Screen Size: 2560 x 1440, resolution is set to standard for monitor
macOS Big Sur 11.7.10
MouseInfo 0.1.3
Pillow version 8.0.1
PyAutoGUI version 0.9.52
Digital Color Meter version 5.22
Python version 3.12.0

I measure the coordinates of some points on my screen with MouseInfo and get their pixel values with Digital Color Meter. I am working in the Terminal.

pyautogui.pixel() does not return correct pyscreeze.RGB objects (RGB values differ significantly from the ones measured with MousInfo and Digital Color Meter).

I expected the function to return the same RGB pixel information as Digital Color Meter has measured.

What causes this problem and how can I fix it?

I realized that pyautogui.locateOnScreen() does not work either on my screen (maybe because of the same problem)

I posted the problem also on the github page: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/830